# How to elegantly add spaces around a substring if there are none?

Tags: python, regex, string

inputs:

```
"bla&&bla...bla &&bla...bla&& bla...bla && bla"
```

output:

```
"bla && bla...bla && bla...bla && bla...bla && bla"
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
str    = "if((a&&b)||c)";
wrong  = "&&";
right  = " && ";

startFrom = 0
wi = 0
while wi != -1
    wi = str.find(wrong, startFrom)
    ri = str.find(right, startFrom) + 1
    startFrom = wi + 1
    if wi != ri
        pre  = wi - 1
        post = wi + len(wrong)
        if str[pre] != " "
            str = str[:pre] + " " + str[pre:]
        if str[post] != " "
            str = str[:post] + " " + str[post:]
```

Is there a clean readable way to do the same thing?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or use this pattern and replace with white space

```
(?<!\s)(?=&&)|(?<=&&)(?!\s)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/186)

Comment: Awesome! Very clever, capturing the empty string in the right spot like that. Color me impressed. Truly love this answer.

Comment: If anybody needs it, here is what I used to capture the operators I was looking for:

`r'(?<!\s)(?=(==|&&|>>|<<|\|\|))|(?<=(==|&&|>>|<<|\|\|))(?!\s)'`

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
>>> s = "if((a&&b)||c) && b"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!\s)(&&)(?!\s)', r' \1 ', s)
'if((a && b)||c) && b'
```

The above regex would capture the `&&` string only if it's not preceded and followed by a space.

**Update:**

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s*&&\s*', r' && ', 'bla&&bla...bla &&bla...bla&& bla...bla && bla')
'bla && bla...bla && bla...bla && bla...bla && bla'
```

OR

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s+&&(?!\s)|(?<!\s)&&\s+|(?<!\s)&&(?!\s)', r' && ', "bla&&bla...bla &&bla...bla&& bla...bla && bla")
'bla && bla...bla && bla...bla && bla...bla && bla'
```

- `(?<!\s)` Negative lookbehind which asserts that the match won't be preceded by a space character.
- `(?!\s)` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by a space character.

Comment: What about not proceeded or mot followed? It replaces all of them right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to complicate, you can do [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
>>> str = "bla&&bla...bla &&bla...bla&& bla...bla && bla"
>>> str.replace('&&',' && ').replace('  &&',' &&').replace('&&  ','&& ')
'bla && bla...bla && bla...bla && bla...bla && bla'
```